# no puedo ejecutar CONDA DEACTIVATE desde un script en LINUX

Tags: linux, script, vim

en VIM escribi el siguiente script llamado ejercicio20.sh

#!/bin/bash
conda deactivate

luego otorgue los permisos de ejecucion
chmod u+x ejercicio20.sh

Luego ejecute:
./ejercicio20.sh

y el resultado es
CondaError: Run 'conda init' before 'conda activate'